# Unable to update state in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to update the the state on the basis of a condition.

Please refer to the code and point out the problem in either the logic or code.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      backImgIndex: 1
    };
    this.changeSlide = this.changeSlide.bind(this);
  }

  changeSlide() {
    if (this.state.backImgIndex === 3) ({
      this.setState = {
        backImgIndex: 1
      });
    } else {
      this.setState = ({
        backImgIndex: this.state.backImgIndex + 1
      });
    }
  }

render() {
    const imageURL = '/backImg/b' + this.state.backImgIndex + '.jpg';
    return (
      <Fragment>
         <BackgroundSlider backurl={imageURL} />
         <div className="slider">
           <div className="left-arrow" style={{}} onClick={this.changeSlide} />
         </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Is there any other way to update the same.

The end goal is to update the state which trigger the update in the background image upon the press of .left arrow.

Can div be used for such an event ?

Comment: changeSlide() {
    console.log('Original State:  ' + this.state.backImgIndex);
    if (this.state.backImgIndex === 2) {
      this.setState = ({
        backImgIndex: 1
      });
      console.log('Back Img was 2. Updated State: ' + this.state.backImgIndex);
    } else {
      this.setState = ({
        backImgIndex: this.state.backImgIndex + 1
      });
      console.log('Back Img was 1. Update State: ' + this.state.backImgIndex);
    }
  }

Comment: Response from console on pressing the div three times- 

Original State:  1
App.js:43 Back Img was 1. Update State: 1
App.js:32 Original State:  1
App.js:43 Back Img was 1. Update State: 1
App.js:32 Original State:  1
App.js:43 Back Img was 1. Update State: 1

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the update in the wrong way. `setState` is a function that should be called in order for updating the `state`. In fact, you are overriding such function:

```
this.setState = {
  backImgIndex: 1
};
```

So, what you need is to call `setState` and pass in the part of the state you wanna update:

```
this.setState({ backImgIndex: 1 });
```

This works:

```
changeSlide() {
  if (this.state.backImgIndex === 3) {
    this.setState({
      backImgIndex: 1
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      backImgIndex: this.state.backImgIndex + 1
    });
  }
}
```

#### Final code

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      backImgIndex: 1
    };
    this.changeSlide = this.changeSlide.bind(this);
  }

  changeSlide() {
    if (this.state.backImgIndex === 3) {
      this.setState({
        backImgIndex: 1
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        backImgIndex: this.state.backImgIndex + 1
      });
    }
  }

render() {
    const imageURL = '/backImg/b' + this.state.backImgIndex + '.jpg';
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <BackgroundSlider backurl={imageURL} />
        <div className="slider">
          <div className="left-arrow" style={{}} onClick={this.changeSlide} />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem was not using the curly braces ?
because if that's the case , prettier in VSCode is removing them ...

Comment: Thanks Josue Cortina

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax in `setState`.

Plus, i would recommend preparing the new state before setting it:

```
changeSlide() {
        let imgI=this.state.backImgIndex;
        imgI=(imgI===3)?1:imgI+1;
        this.setState({ backImgIndex: imgI});
      }
```

Actually, a better option (because [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)):

```
changeSlide() {
    this.setState((state,props)=>(state.backImgIndex===3?{ backImgIndex: 1}:{ backImgIndex: state.backImgIndex+1}));
}
```

Comment: A bit late. Dont you think?

Comment: Can you please elaborate why we had to use imgI instead of setting the state like above.
I want to know so as to clear this concept.

Comment: @SID this is exactly what is called **injustice**. My answer is better and **was posted first**

Comment: You dont have to save anything in a different variable

Comment: @SID It is not  a good practice since State updates may be asynchronous. Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I suggest you to use the ES6 syntax for more clarity :

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      backImgIndex: 1
    };
  }

  changeSlide = () => {
    if (this.state.backImgIndex === 3) {
      this.setState = ({
        backImgIndex: 1
      });
    } else {
      this.setState = ({
        backImgIndex: this.state.backImgIndex + 1
      });
    }
  }

render() {
    const imageURL = `/backImg/b'${this.state.backImgIndex}.jpg`;
    return (
      <Fragment>
         <BackgroundSlider backurl={imageURL} />
         <div className="slider">
           <div className="left-arrow" style={{}} onClick={this.changeSlide} />
         </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I changed your function to an arrow function, and used the template string for your imageURL.
I think that the problem is in your setState. Can you please log the result of `this.state.backImgIndex` after updating the state ?

EDIT : As pointed out in the other comments, you're updating your state the wrong way. I corrected it in this example so you can have a clean example

Comment: This wont fix the problem

Comment: I suggested a new syntax for clarity, never pretended it would fix the issue. Note that I also suggested where the problem could be... 
But thanks for downvoting the other's answers, that's really encouraging people for offering their help...

Comment: As you said, you suggested where the problem could be... nothing more. Those suggestions fit perfectly as comments. Actually, you did not solved the issue of the OP. Thats the reason of why **I downvoted your "answer"**, because, in fact, its wrong.